# Raspberry Pi WiFi communication dedicated thread

Tags: multithreading, raspberry-pi, wifi, communication, raspberry-pi3

I would like to know if it is possible to dedicate one of the four threads of Raspberry Pi for the sole purpose of handling WiFi communication?

I reason i want to do it is because i am unable to perform a SSH connection with my Raspberry Pi  near a swimming pool. I have already tried performing SSH away from the pool and it works fine there. Once the connection is established then everything works fine.

So i was wondering that maybe i will be decode the issue if i dedicate a WiFi thread. Thanks!

Comment: What is it that you have heard or read that leads you to suspect that dedicating a single core to Wifi communications might help in this situation?

Comment: I was hoping to that if the WiFi communication was on a different thread then i would be able to decode whether my scripts are making the communication stuck or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're describing moving the Pi, and not your laptop/desktop/phone, and that there's an access point in the mix. If that's not correct, please clarify.

If you're finding yourself unable to ssh into a Pi, the standard culprits are signal strength (due to distance or obstacles) and interference from other traffic on the channel. Processing power on the Pi, including what's running on what thread, is barely a factor.

The Pi 3's built-in antenna is adequate when close to an access point, but doesn't work well (in my experience) at any significant distance. If you need to move a Pi further out, consider using an USB WiFi that has an antenna instead of the built-in WiFi.